# Slurm: error in reading shell script when using mpirun. How can I fix this?

Tags: r, shell, parallel-processing, mpi, slurm

I am submitting a job on the debug queue on Niagara (Slurm scheduler) and am getting the following error:

```
SALLOC: error: _fork_command: Unable to exec command "/mypath/test.sh": Permission denied
```

I have checked the permissions of the file test.sh and it is readable, in fact I have been using the same file for serial jobs with no problems. I am trying to use mpirun for a parallel job and that's when I get the error.

My shell script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --account= xxxx  
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --ntasks=160
#SBATCH --time=3:30:00
#SBATCH --job-name "sNucRNASeq"

pushd /mypath/
mpirun --np 4 R --no-save < Rscript test.R
Rscript test.R
```

I have tried chmod -rwx test.sh, it did not make a difference.
Am I missing something with regards to letting all the processors access the file? How can I by-pass the error?

The test.R script referred to above is pretty simple:

```
library(pbdMPI)

init()

rank<-comm.rank()
size<-comm.size()

myfiles<-load("ListofFiles.RData")

y <- scatter(lapply(myfiles, readRDS))
comm.print(str(y))


finalize()
```

Comment: what is `test.sh`?

Comment: It is the name of the shell script

Comment: Resolved the error by running chmod +x test.sh. For some reason, permission to execute was off

Comment: `chmod -rwx test.sh` will have removed execute (and other) permissions.